# IBM Websphere 7 set/add http header value

Tags: java, http, websphere

I'm using IBM Websphere 7 and am running into a problem when I try to add a value to the http header (X-UA-Compatible : IE=edge,chrome=1). It is telling me that the response has already been committed and the value cannot be added. If there is a configuration that you could setup in Websphere 7 to automatically add this to the response header that would be perfect.

Comment: I'm not aware of a configuration that will always add this. However, the error that the response has already been committed means that prior to your `response.setHeader(...)` call, some other code has written to the response's output stream - even just a little - and the container (WebSphere) has already written some output to the socket.  You can't send the client headers if your app has already written some/all of the body; headers must come first per HTTP RFC.  If you post your code, more guidance can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with was to create a filter that would execute early on in the processing of the request. That filter would add the values to the response header. It's a workaround and wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it works for now.