# Configure websphere to send java web pages compatible to IE 11

Tags: http-headers, websphere, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

We have legacy java web application running on WebSphere Apllication server 8.0. Required to make compatible with IE11 with minimal changes. Instead of doing changes in each JSP which makes lot of effort and time, we wanted to go ahead with applications level compatibility settings changes to work them in IE11. any suggestions to do so at server level which adds the header part of each request made like this shown below( setting done for .Net applications) [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have http server (Apache/IHS in front of WAS) then you can use solution provided in the link, otherwise you could write a ServletFilter and add that header in the filter.

UPDATE
For IHS add the following in `httpd.conf` (for details check [Apache httpd configuration for IE7 standard mode rendering in IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2008/08/28/apache-httpd-configuration-for-ie7-standard-mode-rendering-in-ie8.aspx)):

- Uncomment (or add)  `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`
- Add the following configuration fragment:

  ```
  <IfModule headers_module>
      Header set X-UA-Compatible: IE= requiredBehavior
  </IfModule>
  ```
- Save file and restart.

Comment: I agree with u. but my problem is i have so many modules redirecting from one to other and having individual web.xml for each of them. All these are deployed in single profile of one WAS. So everybody is forcing me do the settings in server level than for each model.

Comment: If u can provide the complete implementation using servlet filter what u have suggested it wud be grateful. it is something like <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614866/ibm-websphere-7-set-add-http-header-value/24661704#24661704> but it is not the direct solution, just an alternative

Comment: I have tried  1.In the administrative console click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Web Container Settings > Web container.
2.Under Additional Properties select Custom Properties.
3. click NEW and added variable ServerHeaderValue as X-UA-Compatible:IE=EmulateIE8. I hv checked the response header in fierfox by launching the application. the header variable was not updated. though i've added the variable for IE compatibility it should add in the response header right...please help me on this

Comment: @Jayanand  `ServerHeaderValue` is to change server name reported in the headers, not to add custom header. There is no way to do it on WAS. If you have many apps the easiest for you would be to install Web server (IBM HTTP Server is available as separate install with WAS) and WebSphere plugin. Then add the header in the web server and access apps via web server.

Comment: Thanks for the update Gas. Could u pl help me how to the compatibility setting in IBM HTTP server for IE11? means in wch configuration file. please help me on this

Comment: IBM HTTP (IHS) is based on Apache, so follow hints you will find for Apache. The file you need to change is `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will it be the same for IBM HTTP Server which is included as  distribution packages for WAS? pl clarify

Comment: @Jayanand Yes, the same.

Comment: could u please let me know what exact code i need to place in **httpd.conf** file of IHS

Comment: @Jayanand Check [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2008/08/28/apache-httpd-configuration-for-ie7-standard-mode-rendering-in-ie8.aspx). You need to load headers module, and set the header.

Comment: Thanks Gas. I've done it yesterday. The key point which u have given in the begining of having IHS helped me a lot. excellent